# LDA - Linear discriminant function

Tags: r, discriminant-analysis

What is the formula used to compute the posterior probability for LDA in R ? I have a unbalanced class 97% to 3%. Does LDA is good in this case ?

Comment: Cross-posted on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384174/lda-linear-discriminant-function

Comment: Search for `linear discriminant analysis classification` on this site, for formulas. As for highly unbalanced classes - yes it is not very good for classifications. Marginal skew affects power ("sensitivity") of almost every statistical analysis.

Comment: You got an answer in SO. Please delete this one.